# How will center of a group influence its representations

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

If a group $G$ contains an element $M$ so that:

1. $M$ commutes with every element. (It is in the center of $G$)
2. $M^2=I$, where $I$ is the identity. ($M$ has order 2)

then in every matrix representation, $M$ should be represented by matrix of eigenvalues of $\pm 1$. Since $M$ commutes with every element. Every irreducible representation should live in only one eigenspace (vectors in the representation space share the same $M$ eigenvalue) of $M$.

My guess is: if there is one irreducible representations of eigenvalue $+1$, there should be a corresponding irreducible representations of eigenvalue $-1$. Furthermore, this map should be bijective and preserve dimensions of representations.

Intuitively, I think this is true since there is no difference between +1 and -1 eigenspaces. However, I cannot prove it and cannot find a counter example. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quaternion group $Q_8$ has precisely one irreducible representation of degree two. The central element $i^2 = -1$ corresponds to the negative identity matrix, so its only eigenvalue is -1. In particular, there is no other irreducible degree 2 representation, where $i^2$ has a positive eigenvalue.